# Spinner erro ao popular pelo SQLite

Tags: java, android

**Erro:**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col
>   -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

**Classes**

- NovoRegistro: Classe da activity que trará o `spinner`
- ControllerClientes: Classe que controla as requisições, etc.
- DBCreate: Classe que cria o banco.

Classe `DBCreate`

```
public class DBCreate extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "db_pv.db";
    protected static final String TABELA = "clientes";
    protected static final String ID = "_id";
    protected static final String HANDLE = "handle";
    protected static final String NOME = "nome";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;

    public DBCreate(Context context) {
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABELA + " ("
                + ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,"
                + HANDLE + " INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
                + NOME + " TEXT NOT NULL"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        insereTeste(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void insereTeste(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO clientes (handle, nome) VALUES (1,'Cliente 1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO clientes (handle, nome) VALUES (2,'Cliente 2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO clientes (handle, nome) VALUES (3,'Cliente 3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO clientes (handle, nome) VALUES (4,'Cliente 4')");
    }

}
```

Classe `ControllerClientes`

```
public class ControllerClientes {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DBCreate banco;

    public ControllerClientes(Context context){
        banco = new DBCreate(context);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getClientes(){
        sqLiteDatabase = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> clientes = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes",null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                clientes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return clientes;
    }

}
```

Classe `NovoRegistro`

```
public class NovoRegistro extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spnClientes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo_registro);

        spnClientes = findViewById(R.id.spnClientes);
        spinnerClientes();
    }

    public void spinnerClientes() {
        ControllerClientes ctClientes = new ControllerClientes(this);
        ArrayList<String> clientes = ctClientes.getClientes();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido !

O erro estava na linha:

```
clientes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
```

Alterado:

```
clientes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
```

Vou deixar o tópico para posterior consulta de estrutura.